# converting list to dictionary and adding values to them

Tags: python

I have a `list` I want to convert to `dictionary` and add corresponding random `values` to them, tried the previous answers here nothing seemed to work.

This is the `list`:

```
wordlist = ["apple","durian","banana","durian","apple","cherry",
            "cherry","mango","apple","apple","cherry","durian","banana",
            "apple","apple","apple","apple","banana","apple"]
```

Any answer with simple syntax will be appreciated.

Comment: what does *convert to Python* mean? The `list` you have is already a valid Python `list`. No conversion required. Your problem is overall very poorly explained.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to convert to python`?

Comment: Think OP means `dictionary`

Comment: "in python" was just to specify that the program was in python, nothing more

Comment: You didn't say "in python", you said "to python", as in "convert to python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase, the OP is looking for a `dictionary` (think he is), just do :

```
>>> import random
>>> d = {}
>>> for key in set(wordlist):                      #note use of `set`
        d[key] = random.randint(0,1000)            #the (beg,end) value is your choice

>>> d
=> {'apple': 816, 'mango': 342, 'banana': 231, 'durian': 765, 'cherry': 186}
```

Otherwise, if he wants the list with values in a `tuple`, just do:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for key in wordlist: 
        l.append( (key,random.randint(0,1000)) ) 

>>> l
=> [('apple', 645), ('durian', 4), ('banana', 451), ('durian', 550), ('apple', 772), 
    ('cherry', 800), ('cherry', 972), ('mango', 448), ('apple', 783), ('apple', 433), 
    ('cherry', 733), ('durian', 210), ('banana', 656), ('apple', 196), ('apple', 25), 
    ('apple', 395), ('apple', 98), ('banana', 589), ('apple', 695)]
```

---

#driver value

```
IN : wordlist = ["apple","durian","banana","durian","apple","cherry",
                "cherry","mango","apple","apple","cherry","durian","banana",
                "apple","apple","apple","apple","banana","apple"]
```

Comment: thanks this answers my question,

Answer (score -1):

Not a too hard problem. Just need to import numpy to obtain random values.

```
import numpy as np

wordlist = ["apple","durian","banana","durian","apple","cherry", "cherry","mango","apple","apple","cherry","durian","banana", "apple","apple","apple","apple","banana","apple"]

values = [np.random.random() for x in range(len(wordlist)]
d = {*zip(wordlist,values)}
print (d)
```

{('cherry', 0.9664602705758596), ('cherry', 0.42093671361304286), ('cherry', 0.6516552865418069), ('apple', 0.09858653336142964), ('banana', 0.3976892252830715), ('apple', 0.9495323589015604), ('apple', 0.8118746084650151), ('apple', 0.3174994273783074), ('banana', 0.04230289240363949), ('apple', 0.35558531683946804), ('durian', 0.09960999590643527), ('durian', 0.2164173276423449), ('mango', 0.5978643178837114), ('durian', 0.8401078154686553), ('apple', 0.7398063632475643), ('apple', 0.5284715524820693), ('apple', 0.38801846246977323), ('banana', 0.5548286775310872), ('apple', 0.6945371327360194)}

Comment: That's a set, not a dictionary. Why on earth would you use Numpy for this? Just import `random` and call its functions directly.